# Creating exceptions in Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms

How do I create exceptions for more than one field to show up?

I.e.: I own a dog kennel, and if someone is bringing 3 dogs I want them to click (3) in the "How many dogs will be staying with us?" field. I then cannot make it show the info for 1st dog, 2nd dog, and 3rd dog. Only the 1st and 3rd dog show up. Same happens for if they have 4 dogs.

Having 1 or 2 dogs is working fine.

Comment: Would you be able to submit a Support Request(http://help.cognitoforms.com/request-help)? I believe we can help you with your issue, I believe that the calculation needs a little help. I can help you with this if we can take a look at your form and your calculation.